# How do you know when two objects are entangled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I’m not asking how would you entangle two objects. I want to know how would you know they are entangled?

Comment: van Enk _et al_ (2007), "Experimental procedures for entanglement verification," _Physical Review A_ **75**, 052318 (https://authors.library.caltech.edu/8289) reviews a few methods, with emphasis on methods that are sufficient if we _assume that quantum theory is correct_. This is a superset of methods that are sufficient for ruling out local hidden variables.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly thanks, this Looks like a very thorough article and I will read through it.

Comment: What is the difference between "entangled" and "so called entangled"?

Comment: @WillO I say so called because no one knows how two particles are physically entangled. As far as I’m concerned they are physically correlated. You have three choices: (1) they are correlated like a left shoe and right shoe.  (2) they are physically correlated like vertical polarization. (3) or they are so-called entangled which has no explanation.

Comment: So it’s easy to know how and when two particles are correlated like choice number (1) or (2) above but how do you know when they’re so called entanglement like choice (3)?

Comment: @BillAlsept With all due respect, putting "so-called" in the title of a HNQ thread basically amounts to clickbait. (I'm not saying that it is intentional - just that that is the way it functions in practice.) I have removed it, as it serves no real scientific purpose within the question.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thanks, I appreciate the feedback. That may have been a lousy choice of words. The heart of the question really comes down to Bell’s inequalities and his assumption that hidden variable means particles have only one permanent variable. His theorem begins by saying “No physical theory of local hidden variables”. What would it mean to his theorem if I showed real objects with two variables that when physically correlated do produce the predictions of QM and cos2theta?

Comment: "The heart of the question really comes down to Bell’s inequalities and his assumption that hidden variable means particles have only one permanent variable" - there is no such thing. Maybe you mean to say that you don't understand how the standard proof of Bell inequalities within LHV frameworks already naturally allows for arbitrary numbers of hidden variables. (If that's the case, then ask that rephrased question separately.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty how do you mean it already allows for it? Can you physically describe this so I can understand where your coming from? I believe you are missing my point because real particles can have multiple variables that easily get by the Venn-diagrams and do match the prediction of QM and cos2theta.

Comment: As I said, ask separately, and provide full context. What you're asking in the comments has no actual relation to the text of this question.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty OK new question: Why does Bell’s inequality ONLY account for one variable such as polarization?

Comment: @BillAlsept As I said, ask separately. That means a new thread. Surely you've been on SE long enough to understand that? Completely changing the question within the comment thread is *not* what comments are for.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty OK I posted a new question with full context. See “Do Bell’s inequalities assume particles can only have one variable to consider?” Thanks

Answer (score 21):

In general you can't. That is, if you have just two particles you cannot tell whether they are entangled or not.

Entanglement reveals itself by correlations. For example if you take many pairs of particles you may find that their properties are always correlated, e.g. their spins are always opposite, and this tells you that whatever mechanism is generating the pairs of particles is entangling them. But this shows up only with repeated measurements. A single measurement cannot tell you the particles are correlated since their spins could have the values you observe just by chance.

Comment: Thanks john, I assumed it  involved measuring many pairs. I just wanted to confirm if correlation was the main thing we were looking for. Has anyone ever correlated two large objects which produced measurements of cos2?

Comment: @BillAlsept That's very technically complicated. Measurement affects the object (as does any other interaction). The bigger the object, the harder it is to isolate from all those influences, and the harder it is to have any confidence in your measurement. There's no reason to expect entanglement "stops" at some scale, but there's many reasons to expect that the bigger the object, the harder it gets to *prove* entanglement. But we do know it works on a macroscopic scale, because quantum computers are macroscopic (without relying on entanglement of every individual atom involved).

Comment: @BillAlsept as far as I know [this expt is the largest objects ever entangled](https://news.uchicago.edu/story/scientists-use-quantum-spooky-action-entangle-objects-you-can-actually-see)

Comment: @JohnRennie The article is very interesting but it says the two objects are coupled to a circuit and that the circuit keeps the two objects so called entangled. Isn’t that still just a local process? This is probably more of a question for chat But the only correlations I can think of are mirrored variables from a common source. Which is not really entanglement and why I say so called entanglement. I guess what I’m saying is I could draw up an experiment where many pairs of large objects are correlated with given variables that when tested would give the results of cos2. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- If you only have a single copy of the system, then the task is impossible - you simply cannot tell.
- If you have a large ensemble of copies of the system, but you don't know what state they're in, then you need to find out what that state is. That task is known as **quantum state tomography**, and it comes in a variety of flavours depending on what the system itself is. Generically, this will involve taking a number of correlated measurements in several incompatible bases on both sides of your bipartite state, plus some additional post-processing of those measurement results to reconstruct the joint quantum state.

  Once you do have that quantum state, there are a bunch of different entanglement measures. If your state is pure, then things are relatively simple, and all the different measures will coincide, but for mixed states things are fairly complicated and there is a nontrivial hierarchy of non-equivalent measures of entanglement. Some keywords to look for: entropy of entanglement, entanglement of formation, distillable entanglement, etc.
- If you do know what state you're meant to have, then things are a bit simpler, and you can use an [**entanglement witness**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entanglement_witness). An entanglement witness is an observable $\hat W$ such that its expectation value
  $$\langle W \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(\hat W\hat \rho)$$
  can only be negative if the state $\rho$ is entangled (i.e. it is not separable, i.e. if its correlations are strictly beyond the classical "left-shoe-right-shoe" correlations).

  Unfortunately, there are no universal entanglement witnesses: if $\hat \rho$ is entangled then it is guaranteed to have at least one entanglement witness $\hat W$ such that $\mathrm{Tr}(\hat W\hat \rho)<0$, but not all entanglement witnesses will work for all entangled states. (Hence the need for knowing what the state is for producing the right witness.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to know two objects are entangled is to prepare them that way, say by using an SPDC apparatus.  See Andrew Steane's answer for a better way.

Comment: Yes that would be physically correlating them and there is nothing mysterious about that. Just like polarized photons or left and right shoes you know what one is by looking at the other. Those objects do not need instantaneous communication or spooky action from some special entanglement to explain the situation. Entanglement implies something else.

Comment: @BillAlsept :  i'm curious why you prefer to repeatedly post the same pure nonsense than to read a book.  If this material interests you, why not learn it?  If it doesn't interest you, why keep posting about it?

Comment: I have read most books and articles on it and I continue too. I am very very interested in it and Asking a good question that no one has even tried to answer is not posting nonsense. You are not even trying to understand what I’m asking and that is sad. You’re only resorting to insults or criticism. Most likely you understand what I’m asking but you don’t want to confront it. Two particles can be simply correlated to produce all the predictions of quantum mechanics without some spooky action involved.

Comment: Your reading habits must be quite eccentric if you've managed not to learn that you can use a Stern-Gerlach apparatus to produce pairs of particles that are actually entangled (not just correlated), as evidenced by the fact the outcomes of measurements on such pairs violate the Bell inequalities.    Again:  If you're just not interested, I fully understand --- but then why are you on PSE in the first place?  And if you **are** interested, why are you so resistant to learning the basics?   (If your response just repeats the same nonsense, I won't reply further.)

Comment: How can you use a Stern-Gerlach apparatus to prepare entangled pairs of particles? I typically think of an SG apparatus as a decohering measurement device for measuring a spin component of individual particles.

Comment: @WillO I will take eccentric as a compliment instead of how you intended it thanks. A Stern-Gerlach apparatus produces pairs of correlated particles. Unfortunately you are willing to except some spiritually connected spooky action or unexplained wave collapse to TRY and explain what’s happening. Bell’s inequalities are based on a strict assumption that particles have only one variable. Just consider a bi-variable approach and The inequalities disappear. Bell’s assumptions lock you into Venn-diagram situations where of course you create inequalities. Bi-variable correlated objects are real.

Comment: @tparker:  My bad.  I've edited to fix.  Of course the point that it is possible to create entangled pairs remains.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

If you can measure **entropy** of a collection of identically prepared systems, then you could tell if the sub-systems are correlated.

Suppose the whole system is in a *pure state* $|\psi_{\text{tot}} \rangle$.  The whole system density operator is defined as
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\rho_{\text{tot}} = |\psi_{\text{tot}} \rangle \otimes \langle \psi_{\text{tot}}|.
\end{equation}
The state of the two sub-parts is defined by a partial-trace:
\begin{align}
\rho_1 &= \mathrm{Tr}_2 \, \rho_{\text{tot}}, \tag{2} \\[12pt]
\rho_2 &= \mathrm{Tr}_1 \, \rho_{\text{tot}}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Then compute their respective entropy:
\begin{align}
S_1 &= -\, \mathrm{Tr}(\rho_1 \, \ln{\rho_1}), \tag{4} \\[12pt]
S_2 &= -\, \mathrm{Tr}(\rho_2 \, \ln{\rho_2}). \tag{5}
\end{align}
Entropy of the whole system is 0 since it's a pure state:
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
S_{\text{tot}} = -\, \mathrm{Tr}(\rho_{\text{tot}} \, \ln{\rho_{\text{tot}}}) = 0.
\end{equation}
In general (even when the whole system is in a *mixed* state):
\begin{equation}\tag{7}
S_{\text{tot}} \le S_1 + S_2.
\end{equation}
If there's no correlations between both sub-systems, then $S_{\text{tot}} = S_1 + S_2$ ($S_1 = S_2 = 0$ if the sub-systems are in a *pure* state).

You can say that both sub-systems are *correlated* when $S_{\text{tot}} < S_1 + S_2 \ne 0$.

However, I'm not sure that *entangled* is synonymous to *correlated*.

Answer (score 0):

There are already good answers here; I'm going to expand on one aspect.

Two answers point out, correctly, that with only one pair of particles and no prior knowledge, you cannot discover whether or not they were entangled before you did anything with them such as measure them.

Then a couple of answers show what you can do if you have access to many copies which you have reason to know are all in the same state. You can use entanglement witnesses and/or tomography.

One answer added a hint of something I will expand on briefly. This is that if you know the procedure whereby the pair of particles has been prepared, then you can know they are entangled. WillO mentioned the use of parametric downconversion. However that normally relies on a spontaneous process, with the result that the entangled pairs can only be inferred after the fact by post-selection, so I think it is not the best example to pick. A better example would be something like an experiment with a pair of atoms where you first prepare them in their ground state (or another suitable state) by optical pumping, and then apply to them an entangling sequence of operations such as a couple of suitably chosen laser pulses (something we have done about a zillion times in my lab, and it works fine!)

So the logic of this latter method works is as follows.

1. Perform a fixed sequence of operations.
2. Observe the outcome.
3. Repeat, where in step 2 you carry out different observations each time, so as to build up information on what was the outcome of 1. e.g. After 1 million repetitions you have a lot of information (tomography) about what was the result of step 1.
4. Now repeat the whole sequence (1,2,3), say about one thousand times. The idea here is to check that the set of almost-complete tomographic information acquired each time says the same (to within some precision).
5. You are now ready to declare that, next time you press the button to perform step 1 (just that step, using just one pair of atoms), then the outcome will be that they are in an entangled state.

Finally, I would like to underline that in order to show the presence of entanglement it is not enough merely to show correlation in one direction. This is a basic, simple, beginner-level point, but it seems that there are a lot of people who want to express opinions about entanglement whose knowledge of the subject has not even grasped this basic point.